# Call QnA API, Get Response and Display in Chat Bot Window as Bot Response

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm working on a project using Bot Framework. Now one of the requirements of the project is the capability to search for a QnA result using the QnA Maker Generate Answer API "https://{QnA-Maker-endpoint}/knowledgebases/{knowledge-base-ID}/generateAnswer". We have a Search Box on a Web Page which then passes the "Question" variable to the JSON body which returns the result. I wanted to see if there is a way to display the API result on the actual Chat Bot window.

Thank you!

Comment: Then you can take user input means question into chat window finally return the answer on chat window as well. So yes you could do that.

Comment: Thank you @MdFaridUddinKiron, do you have any idea how I could get the question into the chat window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use BotFramework-WebChat, v4, you can achieve this quite easily. The [04.api/d.post-activity-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/d.post-activity-event) demonstrates a similar use case.

Essentially, after the button is pressed, when an answer is successfully returned from QnA the page will emit an event. The event will make use of Web Chat's `store.dispatch()` method to post an activity to Web Chat that will then send to the bot. The activity can be a message, event, postBack, or messageBack type, as documented [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/packages/core/src/actions).

Hope of help!

Comment: This is very helpful thank you! But is there a way to do this without a button? Like when the webchat loads it automatically trigger the Web Chat event to post an activity?

Comment: I was able to achieve what I need following this article https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/m.enable-composition-mode